# XPages sessionScope variable and DateTime values

Tags: datetime, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I seem to be losing the value of sessionScope variables between XPages when I load DateTime values from a Notes document (not from the XPage). Here is what I do:

I have an EditBox where the contents are set to type Date only:

```
<xp:inputText value="#{document1.datum}" id="datum" defaultValue="#{javascript:@Now()}" required="true">
<xp:this.converter>
     <xp:convertDateTime type="date"></xp:convertDateTime>
</xp:this.converter>
<xp:dateTimeHelper></xp:dateTimeHelper>
</xp:inputText>
```

I then save this to a sessionScope variable :

```
sessionScope.put ("datum", getComponent("datum").getValue());
```

Then I change XPages by doing a:

```
var extCont = facesContext.getExternalContext();
extCont.redirect("xpNextPage.xsp")
```

I then do a sessionScope.get:

```
print (sessionScope.get ("datum"));
```

And the contents are fine.

if I do the same thing with a document that I have loaded:

```
var date:NotesDateTime = doc.getItemValueDateTimeArray("datum");
var start:NotesDateTime = doc.getItemValueDateTimeArray("von");
var dt:NotesDateTime = session.createDateTime (date [0].getDateOnly() + " " + start [0].getTimeOnly());
sessionScope.put ("datum", dt);
```

then switch to the next page and try and load it with:

```
print (sessionScope.get ("datum"));
```

I get a value *null*.

I have attached a screenshot of the problem (I printed other fields as well so you can see it is only the DateTime fields that are the problem). I do notice that the format of the DateTime value is different... could this be the problem?

[image: example of the sessionScope variable problem]

Comment: Can you try storing them as Java Dates to the sessionScope (e.g. ndt.toJavaDate() ) instead of NotesDateTime.  I think the Session scope works similar to beans in that it needs to be serializable.  The NotesDateTime class isn't serializable.

Comment: thank you for the tip Rob - that was the problem - now it's working perfectly :o)

Comment: You're welcome Ursus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NotesDataTime is not serializable, so you cannot store it in the memory. When you use `getComponent("datum").getValue()`, it returns you Java Date not NotesDataTime. Java date is serializable, so its working. 
Try convert your NotesDataTime to Java Date.

```
dt.toJavaDate()
```